# Syntax error in mysql Loop. MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am getting a syntax error at simple_loop: Loop statement saying

```
Unexpected character near ':'
```

in the line simple_loop: LOOP

Please help

```
DELIMITER $$  

CREATE PROCEDURE getTable(fullstr VARCHAR(555))

   BEGIN
      DECLARE a INT Default 0 
      DECLARE str VARCHAR(255)
      simple_loop: LOOP
         SET a=a+1
         SET str=SPLIT_STR(fullstr,",",a)
         IF str='' THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop
         END IF
         #Do Inserts into temp table here with str going into the row
         insert into my_temp_table values (str)
   END LOOP simple_loop
END $$
```

Comment: Let me guess... you're using Workbench?

Comment: Lack of `;` in several places causes trouble.

Comment: It might help to reference the function:  https://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Answer (score 1):

It is a very annoying MySQL syntax related issue: There is a TAB somewhere in you procedure leading to this parse issue.

**Note:** Separate `;`

```
DELIMITER $$  

    CREATE PROCEDURE getTable(fullstr VARCHAR(555))

       BEGIN
          DECLARE a INT Default 0 ;
          DECLARE str VARCHAR(255);
          simple_loop: LOOP
             SET a=a+1;
             SET str=SPLIT_STR(fullstr,",",a);
             IF str='' THEN
                LEAVE simple_loop;
             END IF;
             #Do Inserts into temp table here with str going into the row
             insert into my_temp_table values (str);
       END LOOP simple_loop;
    END $$
```

Comment: if I use ; , I see errors everywhere. So, had to remove it.

Comment: Note that `;` is not needed _everywhere_.  But it was missing several places.